# Using native images in Cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I want to use custom images for tab bar icons, as set in this line using this extension: https://github.com/squerb/cordova-ios-tab-bar (imageName is passed through the extension from the javascript):

```
item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:title image:[UIImage imageNamed: imageName] tag:tag];
```

I'm struggling to work out where I need to put the image in my Cordova project so that it's accessible by the native code. If indeed that's possible.

I've tried this:

```
item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:title image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"www/assets/failed.png"] tag:tag];
```

But that results in this error:

```
2016-02-01 15:52:02.894 MovidiamWeb[2527:1070985] -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a1e33ea8
2016-02-01 15:52:02.897 MovidiamWeb[2527:1070985] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a1e33ea8
```

Answer (score 0):

The second form, referencing a path that is visible in xcode project directory, in cordova's case, 'www/images/whatever.png' should work fine, just had to give it a few goes before it started working for some reason.